# ApostropheCMS - Adding multiple items of a particular field (Array)

Tags: apostrophe-cms

Assuming I have a string field 'Email' but I want user to be able to add multiple email addresses. Is there any string array type field in this CMS ? How it would be possible to provide user 'Add More' button so that he can add multiple email addresses if he wants to. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You would use an `array` field type with a schema of a single `string` field that is an email address

```
     // ... other parts of schema
{
      name: 'emailAddresses',
      label: 'Email Addresses',
      type: 'array',
      titleField: 'email',
      schema: [
        {
          type: 'string',
          name: 'email',
          label: 'Email Address',
        }
      ]
    }
```